# How to setup the startup command for a flask azure web app

Tags: python, azure, flask

I've created a simple flask web app and managed to publish it with CI/CD from azure devops to an azure web app. The pipelines are working except the startup of my app.

If i look at the log files in the webapp this comes up -

logfile default_docker.log:

```
    2020-01-08T13:04:17.017575225Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
    2020-01-08T13:04:17.017579025Z Python 3.7.5
    2020-01-08T13:04:17.017582725Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
    2020-01-08T13:04:17.093756525Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
    2020-01-08T13:04:17.109540649Z Site's appCommandLine: gunicorn --bind = 0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 app: application
    2020-01-08T13:04:17.110379356Z Launching oryx with: -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -virtualEnvName antenv -defaultApp /opt/defaultsite -bindPort 8000 -userStartupCommand 'gunicorn --bind = 0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 app: application'
    2020-01-08T13:04:17.114336587Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20191105.2, Commit: 67e159d71419415435cb5d10c05a0f0758ee8809, ReleaseTagName: 20191105.2
    2020-01-08T13:04:17.116548105Z Found build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'. Deserializing it...
    2020-01-08T13:04:17.118951024Z Build Operation ID: |DGaRVt5jG5c=.2a144509_
    2020-01-08T13:04:17.554659456Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
    2020-01-08T13:04:17.784203265Z Found virtual environment .tar.gz archive.
    2020-01-08T13:04:17.784884970Z Removing existing virtual environment directory /antenv...
    2020-01-08T13:04:17.788272497Z Extracting to directory /antenv...
    2020-01-08T13:04:32.810295030Z Using packages from virtual environment antenv located at /antenv.
    2020-01-08T13:04:32.817794689Z Updated PYTHONPATH to ':/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages'
    2020-01-08T13:04:36.780635398Z usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
    2020-01-08T13:04:36.780670499Z gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: app: application
```

my simplefied app treeview looks like this -

```
    test_app/
      venv/
      application/
        templates/
        __init__.py
        routes.py
        errors.py
        models.py
        forms.py
      app.py
```

i've tried different startup commands in azure portal "general setting" but to no solution

```
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600  app:application
```

EDIT : added app.py and **init**.py

app.py:

```
from application import app, db
from application.models import User, Post

@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    return {'db': db, 'User': User, 'Post': Post, 'Classrooms' : Classrooms, 'ClassSession' : ClassSession, 'Teacher' : Teacher}
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import os
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

from application import routes, models, errors

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # * --- DEBUG MODE: --- *
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True)
```

can anybody point me a direction to where i can solve this stupid problem.
thx a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gunicorn command isn't actually pointing to the WSGI `app` object.  Try this instead:

```
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600  application:app
```